# position fixed on bottom not working in css

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

i am trying to image slider and other table row format on small size of images in bottom of the page but if any resize the window then this table in center please help me this used in npm if any solution please suggest me..
Html:-

```
<div id="UsefulTipsDataCtrDiv" class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="width: 5%;background: none">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color:black;"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-inner img-responsive"></div>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="width: 5%;background: none">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:black;"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="tblsmallImages">
                <tr class="carousel-inner-thumbnails"></tr>
            </table>
      </div>
```

css:-

```
 .carousel-inner {
        margin-left: 20%;
        width: 60% !important;
        max-height: 430px;
    }
    .tblsmallImages{
            width:125px;
            height:100px;
            margin-right:5px;
            margin-left:5px;
            bottom: 0!important;
            width: 90%;
    }
    .smallImages{
            height:100px;
            margin-right:5px;
            margin-left:5px;

    }
    .carousel-inner-thumbnails{
            height: 120px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            margin-top: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 90%;
            display: flex;
    }
    #UsefulTipsDataCtrDiv{
       padding:5px 5px 30px 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: enter link description here]

```css
.carousel-inner {
  max-height: 430px;
}
.tblsmallImages{
      width:125px;
      height:100px;
      bottom: 0!important;
      width: 90%;
      margin:0 5%;
}
.smallImages{
      height:100px;
      margin-right:5px;
      margin-left:5px;

}
.carousel-inner-thumbnails{
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background-color: #ccc;
      padding: 0 5px;
}

.thumbnail {
  min-width:18%;
  width:auto;
  margin:5px 1%;
  }
.thumbnail img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  /* min-height:75px; */
}

/*@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .thumbnail {
  min-width:31.33%;
  width:auto;
  margin:5px 1%;
  } 
}*/
```

```html
<div id="UsefulTipsDataCtrDiv" class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="container">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="width: 5%;background: none">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color:black;"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <div class="carousel-inner img-responsive"></div>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="width: 5%;background: none">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:black;"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tblsmallImages">
          <div class="carousel-inner-thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Try this code. Sometimes it will work for you, if there is any problem let me know.

Comment: if im trying to .carousel-inner-thumbnails class css in position absolute to replace relative is image on bottom in screen but problem is then responsive not working

Comment: @Dip Girase Check updated snippet. Removed table and use div instead. Try it.

Comment: no sir same issue wait ...i am sending in screen short

Comment: @DipGirase: If you wish to add information, edit it to the question, not the answer.

Comment: @DipGirase do you need to remove horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: I have updated the code-snippet. I removed horizontal scrollbar and made it responsive.Try it

Comment: @VSM i need to horizontal scrollbar because my images dynamic

Comment: @ Dip Girase, I have added a new answer for dynamic slider.check it

Answer (score 0):

```css
.carousel-inner {
  max-height: 430px;
}
.tblsmallImages{
      height:100px;
      bottom: 0!important;
      width: 90%;
      margin:0 5%;
}
.smallImages{
      height:100px;
      margin-right:5px;
      margin-left:5px;

}
.carousel-inner-thumbnails{
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background-color: #ccc;
      padding: 0 5px;
}

.thumbnail {
  margin:5px 1%;
  }
.thumbnail img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

/* @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .thumbnail {
  min-width:31.33%;
  width:auto;
  margin:5px 1%;
  } 
} */
```

```html
<div id="UsefulTipsDataCtrDiv" class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="container">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="width: 5%;background: none">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color:black;"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <div class="carousel-inner img-responsive"></div>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="width: 5%;background: none">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:black;"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tblsmallImages">
          <div class="carousel-inner-thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:150px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:137px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:100px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:125px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:115px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:127px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:135px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:100px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:125px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img style="width:135px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLN7GK_-yK_R_Qpz-v4mQPCwiMgYcPMz2Y3nk6-qFsZ79RHf1j">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Try this for dynamic image slider.